# Displaying the last page with an error message when using @ResourceMapping

Tags: spring, jsp, liferay

I have a page with a single button (for simplicity). The button asks the server to generate a file and return it. This works without a hitch. When the server has an issue generating the file (for whatever reason), then rather than give back an empty file, nothing happens. This causes the page to be blank (where-as before it would be the last page I was on with a file getting downloaded).

How can I send an error message back to the previous page (without using AJAX for now) from that function? A blank page with the error message is not what I'm looking for.

**controller.java**

```
@ResourceMapping
public void getFile(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
    String zipName = "myfile.zip";

    try {
        //Do something that might throw an error

        response.setProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        //Write to output stream here
    } catch(Exception e) {
        myLogger.error("Error from throwable: " + e.getMessage());

        //Send error message to user on the last page without getting a blank screen
    }
```

**view.jsp**

```
${lastError}
<form method="post" action="<portlet:resourceURL/>">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Modify File" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="Get File" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get blank page because you did not putting anything to response.

When making ResourceRequest your response is always ONLY what you put in ResorceResponse, 
You never get portal's page as a response (not even part of it).

So what you want to do, as you are trying now, is not possible. You have to change your approach.

Simplest (not best) workaround would be

```
<form method="post" action="<portlet:resourceURL/>" target="_blank">
   <input type="checkbox" name="Modify File" value="true" />
   <input type="submit" value="Get File" />
</form>
```

note `target="_blank"`.

Your controller ...

```
@ResourceMapping
public void getFile(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
  String zipName = "myfile.zip";

  try {   

    response.setProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
    response.setContentType("application/zip");

    //Write to output stream here

  } catch(Exception e) {
    myLogger.error("Error from throwable: " + e.getMessage());
    // write the error message to the response stream here.
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().print("last error");
  }
}
```

This way you get file or error in new window leaving your portal page as is.

Other options: AJAX or your response could be html with javascript that makes request to your portal page with additional parameter for error, ...

Comment: This is the same conclusion I came up with. What about doing a target="hiddenframe" and use an iframe to display the message coming back? The only issue is the iframe's css is all funky

Comment: If using hidden frame/iframe than in case of error you could put javascript into the response that would access parent window and put error message into placeholder element that is present in parent page. That way you don't have to bother with styling iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a form for that? Can't you just use a link with its `href` set to `<portlet:resourceURL/>`?

Also, why are you setting the content type as plain text when you're sending a zip file? I hope it's only for the error scenario.

I think you can split the response generation logic based on the result of the try/catch.

```
@ResourceMapping
public void getFile(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
    String zipName = "myfile.zip";

    try {   

        response.setProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
        response.setContentType("application/zip");

        //Write to output stream here

    } catch(Exception e) {
        myLogger.error("Error from throwable: " + e.getMessage());
        // write the error message to the response stream here.
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, a Form is necessary because there are checkboxes and radio buttons that are also sent that modify what is sent back. The content type was another developer messing with my code. This still doesn't prevent a blank page from showing up.

Comment: Yep, the file is downloaded (even with the wrong Content-Type) and the user is on the same page.